# Arrays of enums are enums in Swift?

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch

I'm following [Apple's Swift/iOS tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson5.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH19-SW1) and it features this line of code:

```
button.setImage( filledStarImage, forState: [UIControlState.Highlighted, UIControlState.Selected] )
```

But the definition of `UIButton.setImage`'s signature is:

```
public func setImage(image: UIImage?, forState state: UIControlState)
```

There is no overload of `setImage` that accepts an `[UIControlState]()` array.

Obviously some voodoo is going on, can anyone explain?

Answer (score 5):

In Swift, the `UIControlState` is not, per se, an enum, but actually a structure. From the language reference for `UIControl`:

> **Control State**
>
> The state of a control; a control can have more than one state at a
>   time. States are recognized differently depending on the control. For
>   example, *a UIButton instance may be configured (using the
>   setImage:forState: method) to display one image when it is in its
>   normal state and a different image when it is highlighted*.
>
> **Declaration**
>
> ```
> struct UIControlState : OptionSetType {
>     init(rawValue rawValue: UInt)
>     static var Normal: UIControlState { get }
>     static var Highlighted: UIControlState { get }
>     static var Disabled: UIControlState { get }
>     static var Selected: UIControlState { get }
>     static var Focused: UIControlState { get }
>     static var Application: UIControlState { get }
>     static var Reserved: UIControlState { get }
> }
> ```

The key here is the `OptionSetType` protocol (to which `UIControlState` conforms), which allows us to do "enum-like" access to the static structures properties, given that these have a `RawValue` that is a `BitwiseOperationsType`. E.g.:

```
struct MyStruct : OptionSetType {
    private var value: UInt
    var rawValue: UInt { return self.value }
    init(rawValue value: UInt) { self.value = value }

    static var Normal: MyStruct { return self.init(rawValue: 1 << 0) }
    static var Highlighted: MyStruct { return self.init(rawValue: 1 << 1) }
    static var Disable: MyStruct { return self.init(rawValue: 1 << 2) }
        // ...
}

let MyOptionsA : MyStruct = [MyStruct.Normal, MyStruct.Disable]
let MyOptionsB : MyStruct = [.Normal, .Disable]

MyOptionsB.contains(.Highlighted) // false
MyOptionsB.contains(.Normal) // true
```

Have a look at the instance methods (see link to language ref below) made available by conforming to the `OptionsSetType`. In addition membership management (e.g. `.contains(...)` as above; also, `.remove(...)`, `.insert(..)`), neat set operations such as `union(...)` and `intersect(...)` are also available.

So to summarize; you are right that the `UIButton.setImage` signature asks for `forState state: UIControlState`, but, due to the `OptionSetType` protocol, the array-looking `[UIControlState.Highlighted, UIControlState.Selected]` is in fact a valid argument for call to structure type parameter `UIControlState`.

Note also, as per my example above, that the structure name can be left out, so sending `[.Highlighted, .Selected]` as `forState` argument would be just as fine.

---

Reference & good reads:

- [OptionSetType Protocol Language Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_OptionSetType_Protocol/)
- [How do you enumerate OptionSetType in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32102936/how-do-you-enumerate-optionsettype-in-swift-2)
- http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2420231

Answer (score 0):

UIControlState conforms to the OptionSetType protocol, which provides convenience methods for handling BitwiseOperationsTypes.  So it's not setImage that's being overloaded, but what looks like an array.  See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_OptionSetType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intf/s:PSs13OptionSetType