# Basic questions about OptionSetType

Tags: swift

I try to get clear of OptionSetType Protocol and I have some basic questions.

1) Does the options is an Array type or a Set type?

2) Can I access each element of options using for...in loop or for loop

thanks in advance

```
let options: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions = [.SkipsHiddenFiles, .SkipsPackageDescendants, .SkipsSubdirectoryDescendants]
```

Comment: About enumerating OptionSetType, compare [How do you enumerate OptionSetType in Swift 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32102936/how-do-you-enumerate-optionsettype-in-swift-2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) no

2) no

see this 'self explanatory' snippet

```
import Foundation

let options: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions = [.SkipsHiddenFiles, .SkipsPackageDescendants, .SkipsSubdirectoryDescendants]

let res = options.rawValue == NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions.SkipsHiddenFiles.rawValue | NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions.SkipsPackageDescendants.rawValue | NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions.SkipsSubdirectoryDescendants.rawValue

print(res) // true
dump(options)
/*
▿ __C.NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions
  - rawValue: 7
*/
```

you can initialize it other way, with the same result

```
let options2 = NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions(rawValue: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions.SkipsHiddenFiles.rawValue | NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions.SkipsPackageDescendants.rawValue | NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions.SkipsSubdirectoryDescendants.rawValue)

options2 == options // true
```