# Converting array of bit indexes to OptionSet

Tags: swift, generics, bit-fields, swift3, bitvector

I'm trying to write a helper function which will convert an array of bit indexes to a class conforming to OptionSet.

```
func getOptionSet<T: OptionSet>(bitIndexes: [Int64]) -> T {
    var result: Int64 = 0
    for index in bitIndexes {
        result |= 1 << index
    }
    return T(rawValue: result) // error
}
```

This fails to compile:

```
Cannot invoke initializer for type 'T' with an argument list of type '(rawValue: Int64)'
```

I've also tried using RawValue:

```
func getOptionSet<T: OptionSet>(bitIndexes: [T.RawValue]) {
    var result = T.RawValue()  // error
```

This doesn't work as well:

```
Cannot invoke value of type 'T.RawValue.Type' with argument list '()'
```

Can this be done? Do I need to add additional constraints on T?

I know it's possible to rewrite this function to use a concrete type, but I want to keep it generic if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem in your code is that `Int64` and `T.RawValue` are
unrelated and can be different types.

But every unsigned integer type can be converted from and
to `UIntMax`, so the problem can be solved by restricting `RawValue` to `UnsignedInteger`.

Using @OOPer's idea to define a custom initializer this would be:

```
extension OptionSet where RawValue: UnsignedInteger {
    init(bitIndexes: [Int]) {
        var result: UIntMax = 0
        for index in bitIndexes {
            result |= 1 << UIntMax(index)
        }
        self.init(rawValue: RawValue(result))
    }
}
```

which can also be written as

```
extension OptionSet where RawValue: UnsignedInteger {
    init(bitIndexes: [Int]) {
        let result = bitIndexes.reduce(UIntMax(0)) {
            $0 | 1 << UIntMax($1)
        }
        self.init(rawValue: RawValue(result))
    }
}
```

All option set types that I have seen so far have an unsigned integer
type as raw value, but note that the same would also work with
`SignedInteger` and `IntMax`.

Example:

```
struct TestSet: OptionSet {
    let rawValue: UInt16
    init(rawValue: UInt16) {
        self.rawValue = rawValue
    }
}

let ts = TestSet(bitIndexes: [1, 4])
print(ts) // TestSet(rawValue: 18)
```

Compare also [How do you enumerate OptionSetType in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32102936/how-do-you-enumerate-optionsettype-in-swift-2) for the reverse task.

---

**Update:** As of **Swift 4**  the `UnsignedInteger` protocol has a

```
public static func << <RHS>(lhs: Self, rhs: RHS) -> Self where RHS : BinaryInteger
```

method, so that the above code can be simplified to

```
extension OptionSet where RawValue: UnsignedInteger {
    init(bitIndexes: [Int]) {
        self.init(rawValue: bitIndexes.reduce(0) { $0 | 1 << $1 })
    }
}
```

without intermediate conversion to a “maximal” integer type.

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful. Is it worth casting everything to UIntMax for 32 bit platforms or is that a non issue? let result: UIntMax = bitIndexes.reduce(UIntMax(0)) { UIntMax($0) | UIntMax(1) << UIntMax($1) }

Comment: @Zmey:The OptionSet type can have a 64-bit RawValue even on 32-bit platforms. If the intermediate  value is 32-bit only then you lose bits.  But you don't need `UIntMax($0)` or `UIntMax(1)`, those types are inferred automatically.  – Actually I made that wrong in between as you can see from the edit history. It should be correct now.

Comment: @Zmey: The intermediate result/accumulator could also have the type RawValue. The problem is that the left-shift operator `<<` is not defined in the (Un)SignedInteger protocol, so you would have to define additional protocol extensions for all possible raw types, which I tried to avoid. – In revision 1 of this answer I solved that by multiplication instead of left-shift. So it is possible, but I found this code more elegant.

Comment: @Zmey: Things became simpler in Swift 4, see updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

You may need a little more setups to make your `getOptionSet` to work:

```
protocol OptionBitShiftable: IntegerLiteralConvertible {
    func << (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func |= (lhs: inout Self, rhs: Self)
}
extension Int64: OptionBitShiftable {}
extension UInt64: OptionBitShiftable {}
//...
```

With those above, you can write your `getOptionSet` like this:

```
func getOptionSet<T: OptionSet where T.RawValue: OptionBitShiftable>(bitIndexes: [T.RawValue]) -> T {
    var result: T.RawValue = 0
    for index in bitIndexes {
        result |= 1 << index
    }
    return T(rawValue: result)
}
```

Usage:

```
struct MyOptionSet: OptionSet {
    var rawValue: Int64
    init(rawValue: Int64) {
        self.rawValue = rawValue
    }
}
let myOption: MyOptionSet = getOptionSet(bitIndexes: [1,2,3,5,7])
print(myOption.rawValue) //->174(=2+4+8+32+128)
```

Or, you can define an initializer like this:

```
extension OptionSet where RawValue: OptionBitShiftable {
    init(bitIndexes: [RawValue]) {
        var result: RawValue = 0
        for index in bitIndexes {
            result |= 1 << index
        }
        self.init(rawValue: result)
    }
}
```

Which you can use as:

```
let alsoMyOption = MyOptionSet(bitIndexes: [4, 6])
print(alsoMyOption.rawValue) //->80(=16+64)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great! @martin-r addition is also very useful for converting from array of Int-s.

Comment: Sadly I can't accept both answers, I'm marking Martin's one because it doesn't require defining additional protocols, I went with it in the app. But I very much appreciate your help!